# How to exlude app users from Taggable Friends using Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to exclude non app users from taggable friends

I know with latest version of facebook , it has 2 separate api to retrieve app users through /friends and non app users through /taggable, but taggable friends api is also returning app users

is there any way to separate them?

Answer (score 0):

With v2.0+ not really.  You could use me/invitable_friends but that permission has to be reviewed and it is only allowed for Games on the Facebook Canvas to invite friends to an app and for no other purpose.